# No time to check an answer before the end of the grace period

Tags: discussion, bounty

I get an answer for a question with a bounty:

[Positivity of the alternating sum of indices for boolean interval of finite groups](https://mathoverflow.net/q/232039/34538)

The problem is that the answer came 2 hours before the beginning of the grace period.
The answer *seems* interesting and the author serious, but I will not have not enough time to check if it is really satisfying before the end of the grace period.

What should I do?
Should I award the answer just by the belief it is satisfying (but without being sure, yet)?

Comment: How about award the bounty, but do not accept the answer (until you check it).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should award the bounty. Frankly, I cannot see any downside to it.

Even if it should turn out to be wrong, what's the problem? You just gave somebody that was kind enough to make a reasonable attempt at answering your question some points that otherwise would just dissolve into pure nothingness.

If you are worried about sending the misleading signal that you checked it while you did not, you could leave  a comment like:

> This answer looks very promising so I award the bounty. I will study it in detail as soon as possible.